# how to efficently use group_by using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I have tables records like below:

[image]

I am grouping them based on by `am`, `pm` and `none`.

What I really need to break down the group_by for `none` to `7` `7` columns as my total records of `none` are `14`.

**Query I am working with:**

```
SlotFormula.select([:id,:doorman,:day]).where(:zone_id => 1).order('created_at
 asc').group_by { |result| [result.doorman] }
```

**Current Results from query are:**

```
=> {["am"]=>
[
#<SlotFormula id: 1659, day: "Monday", doorman: "am">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1660, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "am">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1661, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "am">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1662, day: "Thursday", doorman: "am">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1663, day: "Friday", doorman: "am">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1664, day: "Saturday", doorman: "am">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1665, day: "Sunday", doorman: "am">], 

["pm"]=>
[
#<SlotFormula id: 1666, day: "Monday", doorman: "pm">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1667, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "pm">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1668, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "pm">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1669, day: "Thursday", doorman: "pm">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1670, day: "Friday", doorman: "pm">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1671, day: "Saturday", doorman: "pm">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1672, day: "Sunday", doorman: "pm">], 

["none"]=>[
#<SlotFormula id: 1673, day: "Monday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1674, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1675, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1676, day: "Thursday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1677, day: "Friday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1678, day: "Saturday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1679, day: "Sunday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1680, day: "Monday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1681, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1682, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1683, day: "Thursday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1684, day: "Friday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1685, day: "Saturday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1686, day: "Sunday", doorman: "none">

]}
```

**Expected Results Needed:**

```
=> {["am"]=>
[
#<SlotFormula id: 1659, day: "Monday", doorman: "am">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1660, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "am">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1661, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "am">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1662, day: "Thursday", doorman: "am">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1663, day: "Friday", doorman: "am">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1664, day: "Saturday", doorman: "am">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1665, day: "Sunday", doorman: "am">], 
],
["pm"]=>
[
#<SlotFormula id: 1666, day: "Monday", doorman: "pm">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1667, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "pm">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1668, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "pm">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1669, day: "Thursday", doorman: "pm">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1670, day: "Friday", doorman: "pm">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1671, day: "Saturday", doorman: "pm">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1672, day: "Sunday", doorman: "pm">], 
],
["none"]=>[
#<SlotFormula id: 1673, day: "Monday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1674, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1675, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1676, day: "Thursday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1677, day: "Friday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1678, day: "Saturday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1679, day: "Sunday", doorman: "none">, 
],
["none"]=>[
#<SlotFormula id: 1680, day: "Monday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1681, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1682, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1683, day: "Thursday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1684, day: "Friday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1685, day: "Saturday", doorman: "none">, 
#<SlotFormula id: 1686, day: "Sunday", doorman: "none">
]
}
```

**EDIT**

My other question is: How I can show them as columns not rows?

So,

`r` denotes `result` in below table

`n` denotes `none` in below table

```
   Monday   Tuesday   Wednesday  Thursday   Friday    Saturday    Sunday

am am(mo r)  am(tu r)  am(we r)   am(th r)  am(fr r)   am(sa r)   am(su r)
pm pm(mo r)  pm(tu r)  pm(we r)   pm(th r)  pm(fr r)   pm(sa r)   pm(su r)
n  n(mo r)   n(tu r)   n(we r)    n(th r)   n(fr r)    n(sa r)     n(su r)
n  n(mo r)   n(tu r)   n(we r)    n(th r)   n(fr r)    n(sa r)     n(su r)
n  n(mo r)   n(tu r)   n(we r)    n(th r)   n(fr r)    n(sa r)     n(su r)
am am(mo r)  am(tu r)  am(we r)   am(th r)  am(fr r)   am(sa r)   am(su r)
pm pm(mo r)  pm(tu r)  pm(we r)   pm(th r)  pm(fr r)   pm(sa r)   pm(su r)
n  n(mo r)   n(tu r)   n(we r)    n(th r)   n(fr r)    n(sa r)     n(su r)
n  n(mo r)   n(tu r)   n(we r)    n(th r)   n(fr r)    n(sa r)     n(su r)
n  n(mo r)   n(tu r)   n(we r)    n(th r)   n(fr r)    n(sa r)     n(su r)
```

If someone has more better way to deal with it. Please share as well.

Comment: Do you have the date available in some other column? If not, how should we identify which `"none"` go to which group (first or second), ordered by `id`? Also, notice that your expected result is not possible since you will have two `["none"]` keys, which is not allowed in a hash.

Comment: I didn't get you related to **how should we identify which "none" go to which group (first or second), ordered by id**. Fine, your comments makes a lot of sense. How I can then tackle this? Any proper workaround please? Basically I want them to re-arrange based on `doorman` but with respect to day (monday, tuesday, wednesday....)

Comment: Another question: What happens when you have more than 7 days with either `am` or `pm`? You will always group 7 days no matter the date?

Comment: My question about `"none"` is this: In your expected result, what's the difference between first `none` group and second `none` group? How to decide which row goes to which group?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. I will just showed the results from database as they will be saved (id asc) sort of this i mean to say. Also yes if am or pm will more than 7 days they should also being rendered just we are working for none case. I understand what you mean by this comment. So there are a lot of am, pm and none in db. But we need to show them as row by row for 7 days (one am -> mon to sun) 7 days (2nd am -> mon to sun). does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, apparently there is not difference between 1st and 2nd none. I just want to show my records in 7 days. let me udpate my question as well. See my editted question as well. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't fully understand yet, in your updated table you have also repeated rows, how do decide which one goes up and which one down? (for example: `am am(mo r)` is in row 1 and row 6. What is the rule to set it either on first or sixth row? And the same applies for `n  n(mo r) ` (which is in 6 rows).

Comment: No there is not rule set about it. Lets me explain, am -> query will take 1st am of monday then 1st am of tuesday then 1st am of wed then 1st am of thu then 1st am of fri and till sunday. Then query will check if there are any am left. So, it will again take 2nd am of monday, then 2nd am of tuesday, then 2nd am of wed and till sunday. so all am get fits then the same process will goes on for PM, 1st pm of monday, then 1st pm of tues till sunday. Then again a same process run for none. Does that make sense? this is my requirement basically

Comment: In screenshot: 14 none cases. We will split 14 cases in 7 7. I mean a breakdown of 7. none -> (column starts) Monday to Sunday (columns end) next row (column starts) for another none case(monday to sunday)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144752/discussion-between-gerry-and-learningror).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I really need to break down the group_by for none to `7` `7` columns
>   as my total records of `none` are `14`.

You can use the same query you already have, just add one more iteration, using [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`Enumerable#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), to break each group (that is `["am"]`, `["pm"]`, `["none"]`) into groups of seven objects each:

```
SlotFormula.select(:id, :doorman, :day)
           .where(zone_id: 1)
           .order(created_at: :asc)
           .group_by(&:doorman)
           .map { |k, v| { k => v.each_slice(7).to_a } }
```

First you'll find that `group_by` changed to `group_by(&:doorman)` which will get the exact same result as using `group_by { |elem| elem.doorman }` (notice that the `[` and `]` where removed, so instead of `["pm"]`, you'll get `"pm"`.

Second, we added `.map` which applies `each_slice(7)` to every element of each group, which splits any group larger than 7 in multiple groups of seven each.

Output:

```
[
  {
    "am"=> [
      [
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128968ec0 id: 1, day: "Monday", doorman: "am">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128968d80 id: 2, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "am">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128968c40 id: 3, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "am">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128968b00 id: 4, day: "Thursday", doorman: "am">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289689c0 id: 5, day: "Friday", doorman: "am">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128968880 id: 6, day: "Saturday", doorman: "am">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128968740 id: 7, day: "Sunday", doorman: "am">
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "pm"=> [
      [
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128968600 id: 8, day: "Monday", doorman: "pm">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289684c0 id: 9, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "pm">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128968380 id: 10, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "pm">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128968240 id: 11, day: "Thursday", doorman: "pm">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128968100 id: 12, day: "Friday", doorman: "pm">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128973f78 id: 13, day: "Saturday", doorman: "pm">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128973e38 id: 14, day: "Sunday", doorman: "pm">
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "none"=> [
      [
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128973cf8 id: 15, day: "Monday", doorman: "none">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128973bb8 id: 16, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "none">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128973a78 id: 17, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "none">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128973938 id: 18, day: "Thursday", doorman: "none">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289737f8 id: 19, day: "Friday", doorman: "none">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289736b8 id: 20, day: "Saturday", doorman: "none">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128973578 id: 21, day: "Sunday", doorman: "none">
      ], [
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128973438 id: 22, day: "Monday", doorman: "none">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289732f8 id: 23, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "none">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289731b8 id: 24, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "none">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128973078 id: 25, day: "Thursday", doorman: "none">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128972f38 id: 26, day: "Friday", doorman: "none">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128972df8 id: 27, day: "Saturday", doorman: "none">,
        #<SlotFormula:0x007f8128972cb8 id: 28, day: "Sunday", doorman: "none">
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

This changes your original format a little, for instance is an `Array` of `Hash` objects (original was a `Hash` for `Array` objects), but the main change is the addition of one more level of arrays, where everything is grouped in blocks of 7 objects.

This is not so clear with `am` and `pm` groups since both have exactly 7 items, so you see an array with one array (of 7 elements inside). But with `none` you can see an array with two arrays inside, each of 7 items (i.e objects).

I recommend this approach since it will be easier to iterate and fetch the data with keys such as `:pm`, for example:

```
@slot_formulas[:pm].each do |group|
  group.each do |slot_formula|
    # <SlotFormula:0x007f81289fae38 id: 8, day: "Monday", doorman: "pm"> ...
  end
end
```

But, if you need the format you already have, it is also possible to get, but instead of `map` we will need [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
SlotFormula.select(:id, :doorman, :day])
           .where(zone_id: 1)
           .order(created_at: :asc)
           .group_by(&:doorman)
           .each_with_object({}) { |(doorman, group), result| result[[doorman]] = group.each_slice(7).to_a }
```

It's a little more complicated, but you'll get the same output you had with the extra level of arrays (to break in groups of 7).

Output:

```
{
  ["am"] => [
    [
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fb6f8 id: 1, day: "Monday", doorman: "am">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fb5b8 id: 2, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "am">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fb478 id: 3, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "am">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fb338 id: 4, day: "Thursday", doorman: "am">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fb1f8 id: 5, day: "Friday", doorman: "am">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fb0b8 id: 6, day: "Saturday", doorman: "am">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289faf78 id: 7, day: "Sunday", doorman: "am">
    ]
  ],
  ["pm"] => [
    [
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fae38 id: 8, day: "Monday", doorman: "pm">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289facf8 id: 9, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "pm">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fabb8 id: 10, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "pm">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289faa78 id: 11, day: "Thursday", doorman: "pm">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fa938 id: 12, day: "Friday", doorman: "pm">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fa7f8 id: 13, day: "Saturday", doorman: "pm">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fa6b8 id: 14, day: "Sunday", doorman: "pm">
    ]
  ],
  ["none"] => [
    [
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fa578 id: 15, day: "Monday", doorman: "none">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fa438 id: 16, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "none">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fa2f8 id: 17, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "none">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fa1b8 id: 18, day: "Thursday", doorman: "none">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289fa078 id: 19, day: "Friday", doorman: "none">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289f9f38 id: 20, day: "Saturday", doorman: "none">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289f9df8 id: 21, day: "Sunday", doorman: "none">
    ],
    [
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289f9cb8 id: 22, day: "Monday", doorman: "none">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289f9b78 id: 23, day: "Tuesday", doorman: "none">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289f9a38 id: 24, day: "Wednesday", doorman: "none">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289f98f8 id: 25, day: "Thursday", doorman: "none">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289f97b8 id: 26, day: "Friday", doorman: "none">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289f9678 id: 27, day: "Saturday", doorman: "none">,
      #<SlotFormula:0x007f81289f9538 id: 28, day: "Sunday", doorman: "none">
    ]
  ]
}
```

Either way, you get the grouping of 7 you needed, just use the one you fill more confortable to present your table.

> How I can show them as columns not rows?

You can loop trough the result array like this:

```
<table>
  <% @slots.each do |doorman_groups| %>
    <% doorman_groups.each do |doorman, groups| %>
      <% groups.each do |subgroups| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= doorman %></td>
          <% subgroups.each do |subgroup| %>
            <td><%= subgroup.inspect %></td>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: I have reviewed the whole answer, makes sense and it seems like, it can fullfill the requirements as well. One silly question, I am having difficulty in making table view with this query. How exactly I can fit this all array and hashes into table form just like I have posted in question? I am using the first query that you have recommended as well. Could you please make a similar view in table form? :)

Comment: Basically when it comes to none case, the results does not start from the new row but keep moving to till 14 columns. It should create a new row when each 7 ends. Means at the end of each group or inner groups. Could you please review it in table form and post an output please?

Comment: @LearningROR I'm not sure that the query you asked for will be the best way to show that table, i don't know what each row means. Question: can you update your final table to show the exact example of the final output you expect using your image table as the input?

Comment: @LearningROR Since there are two questions in this post, i recommend opening a new question asking how to draw the table (you can reference this post if needed). That way you'll improve your chances of getting more answers, since more people will view your new question.

Comment: @LearningROR And this question can be either accepted (if it answered the original question) to be used as a reference, or can be removed.

Comment: I can understand what you mean by this. As i have referenced desired output in the question in which I have added **EDIT** word. Let me add the link here so you might understand what I am saying. Please review the link if you can understand what I mean or I will see next step regarding your other comments :) see link: https://ibb.co/iTCkav

Comment: @LearningROR Ok, i get it now, can you share the code you are using to get the table in the image?

Comment: Code: `<% @slots.each do |key| %>
                          <tr>
                            <td><%= "DOORMAN TYPE GOES HERE (AM, PM or NONE)" %></td>
                            <% key.each do |slot, keys| %>
                                <% slot.each do |key| %>
                                    <% key.each do |row| %>
                                        <td><%= row.inspect %></td>
                                    <% end %>
                                <% end %>
                            <% end %>
                          </tr>
                      <% end %>`

Comment: @LearningROR The problem is where you put your `tr` within the loop, check the updated answer (at the bottom) with a sample code that works.

Comment: Massive thanks for your help and support in this regard. I have learnt a lot in past 2 days while working with you :) Stay blessed and have a very good weekend :)